# Return a variable from a WebSQL Javascript command

Tags: javascript, sql, web-sql

I'm trying to query a WebSQL database using Javascript to return the value of the 'id' column for the single highest data line.

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
   //
   // PROBLEM AREA
   // How to get the data into a variable?
   //

   var xyz = 0;

   tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM WORKOUTS ORDER BY id DESC' [],function(tx, results) {
     var xyz = results.row.id, i;
     alert('Alert 2');
     alert(xyz);
   });

}, function(){
    alert('success SELECTING!');
}); // End transaction
```

I believe the query is executing as I am getting the *success SELECTING* alert.
The `alert(xyz)` is simply returning value nil.

How can I get the data from the SQL database into a Javascript variable?

Thanks!

EDIT: The following suggested code change results in a ReferenceError: Can't find variable: results

```
function myTransaction(cb)
{
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM WORKOUTS ORDER BY id DESC', [], function(tx, results) {
        cb(results); }); 
    },function(){
        alert('success SELECTING!');
    }); // End transaction
}

myTransaction(function(results) { alert(results); });
```

Comment: You need to use callbacks..

Comment: `function myTransction(cb) {
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    var xyz = 0;
    tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM WORKOUTS ORDER BY id DESC' [], function(tx, results) {
      cb(results);
    });
  })
}
myTransction(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});`

Comment: Rayon - thanks for your help. Unfortunately that code still isn't doing what I was hoping it would. It's returning a ReferenceError: Can't find variable: results in the console. I will edit the main post to reflect the adjusted code.

Answer (score 2):

A few things to note:

You're missing a comma in your executeSql parameter list

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM WORKOUTS ORDER BY id DESC', [],function(tx, results) {
```

NOT

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT MAX(id) FROM WORKOUTS ORDER BY id DESC' [],function(tx, results) {
```

The results object contains a `rows` attribute, not a `row`.

So you want to use

```
results.rows.item(0)
```

NOT

```
results.row
```

`transaction()` takes 3 callbacks, the first is the callback which will be executed when the transaction is opened.  The second is the error callback and the third is the success callback.  You're using the error callback but treating it like a success callback.

Comment: Interesting tschaible - so my success selecting is in fact not successful? All my notes here suggested I was doing that bit right! That's unfortunate as I have a query before this that is also not working then.